# Is it possible to remember url-variable when using php to refresh page?

Tags: php, html, variables, url, header

I made a product page that loads information from the database, using variables in the URL of the page. But when I use `header("Refresh:0"); the variables get deleted form the URL. Is there a way too prevent this?

HTML:

```
if(isset($_POST["Logout"])) {
    $_SESSION["loggedin"] = "no";   
    setcookie("login", "yes", time()-3600, "/");
    setcookie("name", "", time()-3600, "/");
    header("Refresh:0");        
}
```

URL before logout is pressed:

```
blabla.nl/index.php?id=1234
```

URL after logout is pressed:

```
blabla.nl/index.php
```

Comment: Are you using a `form` to perform your logout? Whats the `action` of that form? Does it include your variables?

Comment: well... Since you're already using a cookie..... Why not storing that value there? just saying... Like: `setcookie("currentProduct","$yourvalue", time()-3600,"/");`

Comment: Yes I am. <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])?>">

Comment: Hmm.. So you can do something like that without using the cookies... As long as the ID is always defined in your URL: `<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])."?{$_GET['id']}?>">`

Comment: Yeah that's a bit of a problem, because it is only defined on the productpage..

Comment: And about the cookie, I think it's nicer if people can open multiple productpages at once, and that wont work if you make a cookie with currentproduct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` does not include any parameters added to the URL, just use an empty `action=""` and it will submit to it's self, including any parameters added to the URL.

Edit: your form should look like this:

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

Comment: This works for the id= , but then it deletes the & if you have multiple variables, like this: id=1234&action=0 -> id=1234action=0

Comment: I updated my answer with what your form should look like - if you're using that the URL shouldn't be changed at all unless your code is doing something else you've not shown us.

Comment: @maxmijn Great, no problem!